# Segment concept in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

My question is, why segment is important for SQL Server and is it enhance the SQL Server performance? If it is enhance the performance of SQL server, how?

Please give the suitable example.

Thanks in advance to those who reply to this question.

Comment: In my point of view, the segment concept used in columnstore index.The below link is related to the columnstore index which is describe you the detail information along with the segment as well.

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/columnstore-indexes-in-sql-server-2012/